# PHP echoing array inside loop data only shows array

Tags: php

I know there is so many questions regarding my question, but I didn't find the solution.

I have Oraacle SQL loop data:

```
$array = array();
$qAccessModule = oci_parse($c1, "
    SELECT
    M.MODULEID,
    M.MODULENAME,
    M.MODULELINK,
    AM.MODULEID_FK,
    AM.GROUPID_FK,
    AM.CHKSTATUS
    FROM
    WA_GA_TBL_MODULES M,
    WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES AM
    WHERE
    M.MODULEID = AM.MODULEID_FK AND
    AM.GROUPID_FK = '" . $getGroupIDFK . "' AND
    M.MODULELINK = 'designationManagement'
");
oci_execute($qAccessModule);
while($dAccessModule = oci_fetch_array($qAccessModule))
{
    $array[] = $dAccessModule['CHKSTATUS'];
}

echo $array;
```

When I echoing the $array, the result is array.

What I want is get the data from looping then make it to be array,
example:

```
$array = array("CREATE", "EDIT");
```

and later will be used for:

```
if(in_array("CREATE", $array))
{
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Comment: USE `print_r` . `echo` dont work on array.

Comment: The $array will be used for: if(in_array("CREATE", $array))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `[print_r][1]` instead of `[echo][1]` use `print_r($array);`

Comment: Later $array will be used for: if(in_array("CREATE", $array))
{
    echo "Got Irix";
}

Comment: what is the output you get when using print_r

Comment: this is the output: Array ( [0] => CREATE [1] => VIEW )

Comment: And you are not getting "Got Irix" from in_array then try trimming the array while inserting to $array,
use  $array[] = trim($dAccessModule['CHKSTATUS']);

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks